# Prevent device of turning the screen on when handling custom action in Notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

Would you please help me with the issue below?

I created a simple app that shows a notification for a incoming SMS. On that notification, I added a button to delete the SMS thru the notification.

Since I have a Samsung Gear S2, that Delete button is displayed on the Smart Watch and I can delete the SMS using my Gear S2.

Main problem is that when I delete the SMS using the Gear S2, the screen is wakening up. When I test using Gmail, same scenario just delete the email and keep the screen off.

So, could you please, help me to undestand why the screen is turning on?

**Here, is how I create the notification (after receiving a SMS).**

```
// Intent used to delete the SMS
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(context, MessagingService.class);
deleteIntent.putExtra("notiID", id);
deleteIntent.putExtra("address", address);
deleteIntent.putExtra("date", date);
deleteIntent.putExtra("body", body);
PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        context,
        id,
        deleteIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Intent used to start the app
Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent clickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        id + 1,
        clickIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Notification
NotificationCompat.Builder notiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
notiBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message_white_32dp)
        .setContentTitle(address)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setContentIntent(clickPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_delete_white_32dp, context.getString(R.string.delete), deletePendingIntent)
        .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000);

Notification mNotificationBar = notiBuilder.build();

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(id, mNotificationBar);
```

**What I tested:**

For now, I move the "SMS Deletion" code to a `Service`. That's why I'm using:

```
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(context, MessagingService.class);
PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(....);
```

But I also tried to delete the SMS using the BroadcastReceiver (same result):

```
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(context, SmsReceiver.class);
deleteIntent.setAction("com.test.simplesms.DELETE_MESSAGE");
PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(....);
```

So, I'm not sure why the action configured by `deletePendingIntent` is turning the screen on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I could fix the error and I'm sharing here for future reference.

After debugging and researching, I discovered that I should extend my notification for wearable devices via `WearableExtender`.

This way, `addAction()` add the actions to Notification Bar while `extend()` add an `WearableExtender` which configure the actions that can be performed by the smartwatch (and this way, you can configure different stuff for Notification Bar and the Smartwatch)

```
// Intent used to delete the SMS
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(context, SmsReceiver.class);
deleteIntent.putExtra("notiID", id);
deleteIntent.putExtra("address", address);
deleteIntent.putExtra("date", date);
deleteIntent.putExtra("body", body);
PendingIntent deletePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context,
        id,
        deleteIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Intent used to start the app
Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent clickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        id + 1,
        clickIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// ADD THIS
// Add a wearable extender.. an wearable action
NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearableExtender = new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender();
wearableExtender.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_delete_white_32dp, context.getString(R.string.delete), deletePendingIntent));


// Notification
NotificationCompat.Builder notiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
notiBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message_white_32dp)
        .setContentTitle(address)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setContentIntent(clickPendingIntent)
        .extend(wearableExtender)  // ----> ADD THE WEARABLE HERE
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_delete_white_32dp, context.getString(R.string.delete), deletePendingIntent)
        .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000);

Notification mNotificationBar = notiBuilder.build();

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(id, mNotificationBar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your SmsReceiver class extends from [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)